# Need to exclude a file from RPM spec file and avoid the .rpmsave extention

Tags: rpm-spec

I have a spec file as below

%files

/ovn/*
%exclude /ovn/python/splash/static/favicon.ico

On upgrade of a image I don't want to replace my favicon.ico if already exists so I want to exclude that file on upgrade but it is making the existing file as
favicon.ico.rpmsave.

How to avoid .rpmsave extension?

Comment: what did the %files section look like before you added the %exclude line? Was there a %config directive before /ovn/* ?

Answer (score 1):

A file that is defined as a configuration file will be replaced in that way. In the `%files` section they are either `%config` or `%config(noreplace)`.

Comment: No the problem with %config(noreplace) is I will get a Warning as below  warning: File listed twice: /ovn/python/splash/static/favicon.ico  

To avoid that warning I went for %exclude but the behaviour is bit different which doesn't suit my requirement.

I am ok if I am able to suppress that warning using some &>/dev/null will work in spec file?

Comment: It's just a warning; I wouldn't worry about it. `%exclude` won't package the file up at all (I think).